# PHP and HTML formatting issue when using tables

Tags: php, html, foreach, html-table

I've been learning this by doing and as such I've come across an annoying problem that I can't seem to fix.

When the contents are echo'd out to the table instead of creating one table containing the contents it creates multiple tables.

I'm getting :

Table1 :

- header1 -------- header2
- achievement1 - achievement
  time

Table2 :

- header1 -------- header2
- achievement2 - achievement time

I'm expecting :

Table1

- header1 -------- header2
- achievement1 - achievement time
- achievement2 - achievement time

I've tried array_merge, I've tried setting the achievement-ID as the key, I even tried multiple foreach statements, but that seems to pull through duplicates as well as creating additional tables.
If someone wouldn't mind telling me what I've done wrong I'd be very appreciative.

```
<?php
// Define cache file
$cache_file = "cache.txt";

// Cache file is less than thirty minutes old.
if (file_exists($cache_file) && (filemtime($cache_file) > (time() - 60 * 30  ))) {

// Don't bother refreshing, just use the file as-is.
$file = file_get_contents($cache_file);

// Our cache is out-of-date, so load the data from our remote server,
// and also save it over our cache for next time.
} else {
$file = file_get_contents('http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/guild/chamber-of-aspects/requiem%20paradisum?fields=achievements');
file_put_contents($cache_file, $file, LOCK_EX);
}

// Decode cache file
$achie = json_decode($file);

// Seperate achievements and timestamps as variables
$achiachi = ($achie->achievements->achievementsCompleted);
$achitime = ($achie->achievements->achievementsCompletedTimestamp);
foreach(array_combine($achiachi, $achitime) as $f => $n){

// Combine achievement number into Link for wowhead script
$achilink = ("http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=". $f);

// Sort out time formatting
$unix = ($n);
$not_unix = $unix / 1000;
$date = date("F d Y @ h:i A", $not_unix);

//Print into table
echo "
<table align=center class=mytable cellpadding=8 style=font-family:verdana;font-size:8pt;color:white;>
<tr>
        <th>Achievement</th><th>Timestamp</th>
<tr>
      <td><a href=\"$achilink\" rel=\"item=$achiachi\"></a></td>
      <td>$date</td>
</tr>
</table>
";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not put the table and th tags out of the loop?:

```
echo "<table align=center class=mytable cellpadding=8 style=font-family:verdana;font-size:8pt;color:white;>";
echo "<tr><th>Achievement</th><th>Timestamp</th></tr>";
foreach(array_combine($achiachi, $achitime) as $f => $n){

// Combine achievement number into Link for wowhead script
$achilink = ("http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=". $f);

// Sort out time formatting
$unix = ($n);
$not_unix = $unix / 1000;
$date = date("F d Y @ h:i A", $not_unix);

//Print into table
echo "<tr>
      <td><a href=\"$achilink\" rel=\"item=$achiachi\"></a></td>
      <td>$date</td>
</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I actually just danced a little. You're a star.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to echo the  and first  for header outsite the for loop